# Call multiple functions within jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

I have multiple functions within plugin that I like to call through out but for some reasons I get *methods undefined*.

If I don't use methods to wrap the functions I get

*function statement requires a name*

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. do I need to wrap the functions with methods var?

   ```
   (function ($) {

   var methods = {

       // GET TARGET LOCATION AND ANIMATE
       scrollTopPage: function () {

           $(htmlBody).animate({
               scrollTop: 0
           }, 'slow');

       },

       scrollToSect: function (htmlBody) {

           $(htmlBody).animate({

               scrollTop: $('#page-id').offset().top
           });

       },

       goToID: function (sectID) {

           var htmlBody = 'html,body';

           //Scroll to the very top
           if (sectID == 'home') {

               methods.scrollTopPage(htmlBody);

           } else {


               methods.scrollToSect(htmlBody);

           }

       }

   } // End the Methods/Functions


   $.fn.pageScroller = function (methods) {


       this.click(function (e) {

           sectID = $(this).attr('id');

               e.preventDefault();

               // Undefined Error
               methods.goToID(sectID); // Call the goToID function and pass the sectID variable

                   $(this).parent().addClass('current').prev().removeClass('current');
                   $(this).parent().addClass('current').next().removeClass('current');


       });

       $(document).keydown(function (e) {

           //To Do Re Use the methods/functions here

       });

   };

   })(jQuery);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a variable, not calling the function at:

```
 $.fn.pageScroller = function (methods) { ....
```

I guess that this results in when the function is actually called from the `$.fn.pageScrollerplugin`, or whatever calls this, the parameter will be named `methods`, but will not be the methods object you created. Instead, it will be whatever the invoker chooses to pass as parameter. In your case, it seems as no parameter is passed at all. That's why `methods` is `undefined`.

If you don't set a parameter for this function, does it not lead to that `methods` will reference your collection of functions instead of a parameter passed?

Ie.: try this, and hope `methods` is still accessible:

```
 $.fn.pageScroller = function () { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

one other way is having `methods` property inside plugin like this...

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.pageScroller = function () {

  this.methods = {

    // GET TARGET LOCATION AND ANIMATE
    scrollTopPage: function () {

        $(htmlBody).animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');

    },

    scrollToSect: function (htmlBody) {

        $(htmlBody).animate({

            scrollTop: $('#page-id').offset().top
        });

    },

    goToID: function (sectID) {

        var htmlBody = 'html,body';

        //Scroll to the very top
        if (sectID == 'home') {

            methods.scrollTopPage(htmlBody);

        } else {


            methods.scrollToSect(htmlBody);

        }

    }

} // End the Methods/Functions



    this.click(function (e) {

        sectID = $(this).attr('id');

            e.preventDefault();

            // Undefined Error
            methods.goToID(sectID); // Call the goToID function and pass the sectID variable

                $(this).parent().addClass('current').prev().removeClass('current');
                $(this).parent().addClass('current').next().removeClass('current');


    });

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {

        //To Do Re Use the methods/functions here

    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

or also you can also pass methods while creating plugin...